# HTML/Javascript Set required id as optional

Tags: javascript

I have this code where in a text box is requried to have a value:

```
<input class="span10" required name="bootloadername" Value="@ViewBag.BootloaderName" type="text"/>
<div id="bootloadernameerror"></div>
```

Is it possible to set is as optional? add a javascript if let's say option = 0 required is not needed and if 1 then required is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using required attribute that:

> The required attribute is a boolean attribute.
>
> When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out
>   before submitting the form.

So you can either remove the "required" attribute or use javascript to remove it on specific conditions.
e.g (if you use jQuery)

```
$(input).removeAttr("required");
```

or either see the other answer if you use plain javascript

Comment: You shud mention use of jQuery as the question doesnot have it in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can set/unset `required` using:

```
//SET
document.getElementsByName("bootloadername")[0].required = true;

//UNSET
document.getElementsByName("bootloadername")[0].required = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add simple if statement ..

```
if( document.getElementsByName("bootloadername")[0].getAttribute('option') == '1' ){
    document.getElementsByName("bootloadername")[0].setAttribute('required', 'required' )
} else {
    document.getElementsByName("bootloadername")[0].setAttribute('required', '' )
}
```